# Recovery data from Unable to mount Sandisk Extreme USB device

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive, ssd, data-recovery

so it seem many Sandisk Extreme devices are crashing recently. The company updated some firmwares but it seems that my device does not need any update regarding the website autochecker, but anyhow my device crashed suddenly and stopped working just like the others. I have tried different ports, different cables and different PCs all with the same result, the device seem to be impossible to mount. I have came here with some logs after many unsuccesful attemps to ask for advice, the data must be there, so how can I access my files before throwing this device to the bin?...

The device is shown in lsusb command:

```
oot@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu/Documents# lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0781:5590 SanDisk Corp. Ultra Dual
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04f3:0c4c Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:ARM-M4
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0408:5442 Quanta Computer, Inc. HP True Vision HD Camera
Bus 003 Device 019: ID 2109:8818 VIA Labs, Inc. USB Billboard Device   
**Bus 003 Device 021: ID 0781:55ae SanDisk Corp. Extreme 55AE**
Bus 003 Device 018: ID 062a:7223 MosArt Semiconductor Corp. Full-Speed Mouse
Bus 003 Device 017: ID 2109:2822 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 2109:0822 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.1 Hub             
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

It is not shown in fdisk -l.

dmesg command already show some errors:

```
[usb 3-3.5: new high-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
[ 2706.114762] usb 3-3.5: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=8818, bcdDevice= 0.01
[ 2706.114772] usb 3-3.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2706.114776] usb 3-3.5: Product: USB Billboard Device   
[ 2706.114778] usb 3-3.5: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.         
[ 2706.114780] usb 3-3.5: SerialNumber: 0000000000000001
[ 3266.184466] usb 3-3.4: new high-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
[ 3266.370416] usb 3-3.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=55ae, bcdDevice=30.00
[ 3266.370427] usb 3-3.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[ 3266.370430] usb 3-3.4: Product: Extreme 55AE
[ 3266.370433] usb 3-3.4: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[ 3266.370435] usb 3-3.4: SerialNumber: 323131334733343034373834
[ 3266.376441] scsi host1: uas
[ 3273.293155] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Extreme 55AE     3000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 3273.296711] scsi 1:0:0:1: Enclosure         SanDisk  SES Device       3000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 3273.298897] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 3273.298982] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Media removed, stopped polling
[ 3273.299095] ses 1:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
[ 3273.299145] ses 1:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 13
[ 3273.299248] ses 1:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
[ 3273.299250] ses 1:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
[ 3273.299335] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 3295.998899] /dev/sdb: Can't open blockdev
[ 3408.901065] usb 3-3.4: stat urb: status -71
[ 3408.901085] usb 3-3.4: cmd cmplt err -71
[ 3409.019836] usb 3-3.4: USB disconnect, device number 20
[ 3409.019975] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#21 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[ 3409.019980] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#21 CDB: Test Unit Ready 00 00 00 00 00 00
[ 3414.924313] usb 3-3.4: new high-speed USB device number 21 using xhci_hcd
[ 3415.110130] usb 3-3.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=55ae, bcdDevice=30.00
[ 3415.110142] usb 3-3.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[ 3415.110145] usb 3-3.4: Product: Extreme 55AE
[ 3415.110148] usb 3-3.4: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[ 3415.110150] usb 3-3.4: SerialNumber: 323131334733343034373834
[ 3415.116516] scsi host1: uas
[ 3422.056730] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Extreme 55AE     3000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 3422.060581] scsi 1:0:0:1: Enclosure         SanDisk  SES Device       3000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 3422.062992] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Media removed, stopped polling
[ 3422.063016] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 3422.063260] ses 1:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
[ 3422.063347] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 3422.063375] ses 1:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 13
[ 3422.063492] ses 1:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
[ 3422.063494] ses 1:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
```

The output of journalctl --follow when connecting the USB show the same:

```
journalctl --follow
Aug 30 21:27:45 ubuntu kernel: ses 1:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
Aug 30 21:27:45 ubuntu kernel: ses 1:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
Aug 30 21:27:45 ubuntu kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
Aug 30 21:27:45 ubuntu systemd-udevd[12249]: sdb: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sdb' failed with exit code 1.
Aug 30 21:28:07 ubuntu kernel: /dev/sdb: Can't open blockdev
Aug 30 21:30:00 ubuntu kernel: usb 3-3.4: stat urb: status -71
Aug 30 21:30:00 ubuntu kernel: usb 3-3.4: cmd cmplt err -71
Aug 30 21:30:00 ubuntu kernel: usb 3-3.4: USB disconnect, device number 20
Aug 30 21:30:00 ubuntu kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#21 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
Aug 30 21:30:00 ubuntu kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#21 CDB: Test Unit Ready 00 00 00 00 00 00
Aug 30 21:30:06 ubuntu kernel: usb 3-3.4: new high-speed USB device number 21 using xhci_hcd
Aug 30 21:30:06 ubuntu kernel: usb 3-3.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=55ae, bcdDevice=30.00
Aug 30 21:30:06 ubuntu kernel: usb 3-3.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
Aug 30 21:30:06 ubuntu kernel: usb 3-3.4: Product: Extreme 55AE
Aug 30 21:30:06 ubuntu kernel: usb 3-3.4: Manufacturer: SanDisk
Aug 30 21:30:06 ubuntu kernel: usb 3-3.4: SerialNumber: 323131334733343034373834
Aug 30 21:30:06 ubuntu kernel: scsi host1: uas
Aug 30 21:30:06 ubuntu mtp-probe[13030]: checking bus 3, device 21: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3.4"
Aug 30 21:30:06 ubuntu mtp-probe[13030]: bus: 3, device: 21 was not an MTP device
Aug 30 21:30:06 ubuntu mtp-probe[13032]: checking bus 3, device 21: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3.4"
Aug 30 21:30:06 ubuntu mtp-probe[13032]: bus: 3, device: 21 was not an MTP device
Aug 30 21:30:13 ubuntu kernel: scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Extreme 55AE     3000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Aug 30 21:30:13 ubuntu kernel: scsi 1:0:0:1: Enclosure         SanDisk  SES Device       3000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Aug 30 21:30:13 ubuntu kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Media removed, stopped polling
Aug 30 21:30:13 ubuntu kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
Aug 30 21:30:13 ubuntu kernel: ses 1:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
Aug 30 21:30:13 ubuntu kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
Aug 30 21:30:13 ubuntu kernel: ses 1:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 13
Aug 30 21:30:13 ubuntu kernel: ses 1:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
Aug 30 21:30:13 ubuntu kernel: ses 1:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
Aug 30 21:30:13 ubuntu systemd-udevd[12249]: sdb: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sdb' failed with exit code 1.
```

The command mount /dev/sdb indicates "no medium found on /dev/sdb."

So what can I do or what options can I try to access the device and recover the data?
Is there any physical approach I can try to access the data inside? Like maybe resoldering the usb connector or something with the PCB (I guess that if the ID is read in lsusb then the device connector should be ok...)  ?

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help me